# Jest API testing giving false passes

Tags: node.js, mongodb, jestjs, supertest, web-api-testing

I have a simple test script for my API, the specific route is not implemented at the moment. But for some reason tests pass. Here is the script:

```
const request = require('supertest')
const api = require('../api-server')

// testing data:
const pmOne = {
    name: "Some Name",
    tel: "234 123"
}

const pmTwo = {
    name: "Some Other Name",
    tel: "256 789"
}



describe('Basic CRUD API', () =>{
    it('GET /pm --> array of all projectmanagers', () =>{      
        request(api)
            .post('/pm')
            .send(pmTwo)
            .expect(207)
    })

    
    it('GET /pm/id --> new projectmanager',  () => {
         request(api)
            .get('/pm/' + pmOneId)
            .expect(200)
            .then((res) => {
                expect(res.body.name).toBe(pmOne.name)
                expect(res.body.tel).toBe(pmOne.tel)
            })
    })
```

And here is my app.js:

```
require('dotenv').config()
const express = require('express')
const mongoose = require('mongoose')
const app = express()
const pmRouter = require('./routes/pm.router')

// establish mongodb connection
var options = {
    user: process.env.DATABASE_USER,
    pass: process.env.DATABASE_PASSWD
    }
    

mongoose.connect(process.env.DATABASE_URL, options)
const db = mongoose.connection
db.on('error', (error) => console.error(error))

app.use(express.json())

//app.use('/pm', pmRouter)

module.exports = app
```

The

```
//app.use('/pm', pmRouter)
```

Is commented out, so the route is not valid. That means all request should return 404 (which they do), so why am I getting passes on my tests:

```
> jest --forceExit --runInBand

 PASS  tests/projectmanager.test.js
  Basic CRUD API
    ✓ GET /pm --> array of all projectmanagers (5 ms)
    ✓ GET /pm/id --> new projectmanager (3 ms)

Test Suites: 1 passed, 1 total
Tests:       2 passed, 2 total
Snapshots:   0 total
Time:        0.571 s, estimated 1 s
Ran all test suites matching /tests\/projectmanager.test.js/i.
Force exiting Jest: Have you considered using `--detectOpenHandles` to detect async operations that kept running after all tests finished?
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Supertest request returns a promise and if you want to assert the returned value it has to be awaited or returned explicitly.

Either return it or use `async/await` syntax.

In your case simply add a `return` statement.

```js
it('GET /pm', () => {      
  return request(api).post('/pm').send(pmTwo).expect(207)
});
```